# I changed rightly the permalinks but I get empty pages in the final posts

Tags: permalinks

I changed my permalinks to pretty ones(nameofcategory/nameofpost). The paths and the urls are perfectly formed, and I can see them when I go on the tittles, rolling over, but when I click, the final post becomes an empty page. I tried everything. Could someone help me? Most I change something in the_permalink or in single.php, or somewhere else to get effective the redirection from ugly permalinks to the pretty new ones?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you set the permalinks to? Can I see the format?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common problem where everyone will encounter, this sounds like there is no htaccess file in your root directory else there is no enough permission to rewrite. Make sure htaccess presence and its permission, hope this will resolve your problem.